# Persisting data into multiple tables at the same time

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

In my iPAD Application, I have 6 UITableViews and to load data for those views, I call 6 different webservices. Each Table view has its own database table/entity.

My operation for each of the tableview is that I would call a webservice using NSURLConnection and then parse the resulting XML using NSXMLParser and persist the data into the SQLite database using `[managedObjectContext save:&error];` command.

I would like to know if there is a way I would be able to persist data into multiple tables in SQLite at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, only you have to take care about the integrity of data, i think some of your tables have some kind of relationship.

Comment: ok.. thank you.. none of the 6 tables have relationship with each other.. they all have a relationship with one main table.. so if I use threading to take care of persisting at the same time, would it be a problem?

Comment: The golden rule to make a multithreaded core data application is to use a unique context per thread and have special care merging information between threads handle NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification. Cheers.